# How to update rows in tables with specific column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to update the `id_ciudad` column in all tables containing it, probably using a script. In addition, this script would be executed in several large databases. The thing is, that some tables are not the same for all databases, but they do have (for sure) this column among them.

Reviewing on internet I could build this piece of script, but it is not functional. With this script, I obtain all tables with the `id_ciudad` and iterate it, but I receive this error

> The column name 'id_ciudad' is not valid

Is there anyone who might be able to help me? :D

```
DECLARE @tabsConCiudad AS TABLE (id_table int, table_name VARCHAR(75) )
DECLARE @id_table as int
DECLARE @table_name as VARCHAR(75)

-- It obtain correctly the tables with id_ciudad column
INSERT INTO @tabsConCiudad (id_table, table_name)   
    SELECT object_id, name
    FROM sys.tables 
    WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id
                        FROM sys.columns
                        WHERE name LIKE 'id_ciudad')

DECLARE _CURSOR CURSOR 
LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR 
        SELECT id_table
        FROM @tabsConCiudad

OPEN _CURSOR

--It iterate the obtained tables correctly
FETCH NEXT FROM _CURSOR INTO @id_table

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    --This part is the bad part, in the update
    UPDATE tab
    SET tab.[id_ciudad] = ciudades.id_ciudad
    FROM [sys].[dm_db_index_operational_stats]( Null, @id_table, Null, Null ) tab, [cw_core].[ciudades] ciudades
    WHERE tab.[id_ciudad] = ciudades.old_id_HO

    FETCH NEXT FROM _CURSOR INTO @id_table
END

CLOSE _CURSOR
DEALLOCATE _CURSOR
```

Comment: make sure `id_ciudad` contain in tab and ciudades tables

Comment: You are asking the wrong question - what are you trying to accomplish? You cannot update a DMV - which is the entity for the alias "tab" in your update statement. In addition, you should **not** by joining in the where clause - use a proper join in the from clause.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Solution by OP.*

To solve it, use EXECUTE with a query string that you wanted to execute. In other words, update the values of the tables that contain a column called `"city_id"`.

```
DECLARE @ciudadDefecto as int

DECLARE @tabsConCiudad AS TABLE (id_table int, table_name VARCHAR(75) )
DECLARE @table_name as VARCHAR(75)
DECLARE @table_complete_name as VARCHAR(175)
DECLARE @queryString as VARCHAR(1000)

insert into @tabsConCiudad (id_table, table_name)   
    select object_id, name
    from sys.tables 
    where object_id in 
        (select object_id
        from sys.columns
        where name like 'id_ciudad_registro')

DECLARE _CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR SELECT table_name FROM @tabsConCiudad

OPEN _CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM _CURSOR INTO @table_name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN 

    Set @table_complete_name =  CONCAT ( '[cw_core].[',  @table_name, ']')
        print CONCAT('Ejecutando: actualizacion a tabla ', @table_complete_name)
    set @queryString =  CONCAT ( 'Update tab ', '')
    set @queryString =  CONCAT ( @queryString, ' set tab.id_ciudad_registro = ciudades.id_ciudad  ')
    set @queryString =  CONCAT ( @queryString, ' from ', @table_complete_name, ' tab,  [cw_core].[ciudades] ciudades ' )
    set @queryString =  CONCAT ( @queryString, ' where tab.id_ciudad_registro = ciudades.old_id_HO' )
    EXECUTE(@queryString)

    FETCH NEXT FROM _CURSOR INTO @table_name
END
CLOSE _CURSOR DEALLOCATE _CURSOR
```